# Android R.java missing

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, r.java-file

I am working with android.I am using eclipse juno. For the last few days I had a problem of missing `R.java` file from my project. I had searched for solutions but those are like `clean the project and rebuild,fix project properties,restart eclipse` etc. I tried all these but still I can't solve my problem. What are the reason for missing this file? How can I resolve?? please help me I am new to android thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. check if there is any error in project. . 2. check if you are importing the right R class.

Comment: there must be error with resource ..try finding out there is proper resources in ur code

Comment: In my experience this is caused by an unrelated error. Look around for problems with syntax or spelling errors in code and xml. And make sure any external libraries and SDKs are correctly referenced. Your R file will come back once your project is error free.

Comment: did you build the project.try to clean and build project.

Comment: R.java file deleted only when there is a mistake with res folder (capital resource name,resource missing etc)

Comment: see in your eclipse problems tab may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

I had facing same problem R.java file automaticaly Remove from the folder. But you can try this Your problem might solve. I am Not Sure this also working for you but that worked for me.

**right click on project > properties > Resources > Android > chage project build target to higher version.**

try this

Answer (score 0):

1.Check errors in the manifest file...

2.check the name of files in drawable that which should not start with the digits like `123.png`

1. avoid spaceing in the string.xml `<string name="appname">AppName</string>` correct
   `<string name="app name">AppName</string>` wrong one

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed my problem,by this solution..hope it will help:

check throughly all of the .xml files(in layout,in menu,in values .in drawable folders etc.),one of them may have some error,as this is the big reason to remove r.java file.If any xml file may have any error fix that error, then build your project again.. R.java again visible in "gen" folder